# How to change language mapbox using android sdk

Tags: android, mapbox

I need to change language of map using mapbox in android. I saw this in oficial mapbox android application, but cant find it in documentation how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

I find answer on my question in source code of this app [link](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo).

And its look like this:

```
Layer mapText = map.getLayer("country-label-lg");
if (mapText != null) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.french:
      mapText.setProperties(textField("{name_fr}"));
      return true;
    case R.id.russian:
      mapText.setProperties(textField("{name_ru}"));
      return true;
    case R.id.german:
      mapText.setProperties(textField("{name_de}"));
      return true;
    case R.id.spanish:
      mapText.setProperties(textField("{name_es}"));
      return true;
    default:
      mapText.setProperties(textField("{name_en}"));
      return true;
    case android.R.id.home:
      onBackPressed();
      return true;
  }
```

Comment: This changes only country names. How to change languages of other labels?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it for Russian language. Next code is in Kotlin, but you can adapt it for Java.

```
    //  Set Russian language if available
    val prop_ru = PropertyFactory.textField("{name_ru}")
    val idArr = listOf<String>(
            "tunnel-oneway-arrows-blue-minor",
            "tunnel-oneway-arrows-blue-major",
            "tunnel-oneway-arrows-white",
            "tunnel-oneway-arrows-white",
            "turning-features-outline",
            "road-oneway-arrows-blue-minor",
            "road-oneway-arrows-blue-major",
            "level-crossings",
            "road-oneway-arrows-white",
            "turning-features",
            "bridge-oneway-arrows-blue-minor",
            "bridge-oneway-arrows-blue-major",
            "bridge-oneway-arrows-white",
            "road-label-small",
            "road-label-medium",
            "road-label-large",
            "road-shields-black",
            "road-shields-white",
            "motorway-junction",
            "waterway-label",
            "rail-label",
            "water-label-sm",
            "place-residential",
            "airport-label",
            "place-islet-archipelago-aboriginal",
            "place-neighbourhood",
            "place-suburb",
            "place-hamlet",
            "place-village",
            "place-town",
            "place-island",
            "place-city-sm",
            "place-city-md-s",
            "place-city-md-n",
            "place-city-lg-s",
            "place-city-lg-n",
            "marine-label-sm-ln",
            "marine-label-sm-pt",
            "marine-label-md-ln",
            "marine-label-md-pt",
            "marine-label-lg-ln",
            "marine-label-lg-pt",
            "state-label-sm",
            "state-label-md",
            "state-label-lg",
            "country-label-sm",
            "country-label-md",
            "country-label-lg"
            )

    for (id in idArr)
        map.getLayer(id)?.setProperties(prop_ru)

    //  Set label size for house numbers
    map.getLayer("housenum-label")?.setProperties(PropertyFactory.textSize(17f))
```